# Dapr - "failed to invoke, id: webapi, err: couldn't find service: webapi"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, dapr

I have a .NET Web API where I have installed `dotnet add package Dapr.AspNetCore` and have included this in the service collection:

```
services.AddControllers().AddDapr();
app.UseEndpoints(e =>
{
    e.MapSubscribeHandler();
    e.MapControllers();
});
```

I have this `POST` method:

```
// Route is /login
[Route(Program.ROOT + Program.TOKEN)]
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody][Required] JsonDocument jsonData)
{
    IResult result = await Task.Run(() => _userCommander.LoginUser(jsonData));
    return result.Ok ? Ok(result.Value) : BadRequest(result.Value);
}
```

I runned dapr init and have the config filed in `$HOME/.dapr`.
I currently only run the dapr locally with this terminal command inside the API folder where `program.cs` is located. I have tried both with and without the app-protocol:

```
dapr run --app-id webapi --app-port 51669 --dapr-http-port 3500 --app-protocol=https -- dotnet run
```

When I then use dapr list I can verify that the WebAPI service is running:

```
 APP ID  HTTP PORT  GRPC PORT  APP PORT  COMMAND     AGE  CREATED              DAPRD PID  CLI PID  APP PID
 webapi  3500       53942      51669     dotnet run  3m   2023-11-13 13:56.24  8192       8184     8193
```

When I try to send a post request to my endpoint it cannot find the service to invoke. I send the Json body I need to send with the url below through Postman:

```
http://localhost:3500/v1.0/invoke/webapi/method/login
```

Which results in this error message here:

```
{
    "errorCode": "ERR_DIRECT_INVOKE",
    "message": "failed to invoke, id: webapi, err: couldn't find service: webapi"
}
```

I do not understand why it cannot find the WebAPI service when I use dapr list and can see the service there. In the image below there is logs for when I run the dapr on my project.

[image: dapr-logs]

Answer (score 0):

There are certain anti-virus/security software that may block mdns requests (which is what dapr uses for service discovery when running locally).

**For me, disabling the McAfee solved this.**

It worked well with my VPN. but this also could help to try diable and check again while the VPN is off.